# gcc being built with fno-exceptions

Tags: exception, gcc, build, libstdc++

I am trying to build gcc5.4.0. My configure command looks something like this:

```
../"$GCC_SRCDIR"/configure --prefix="$PREFIX" --with-sysroot="$PREFIX" --with-gxx-include-dir="$PREFIX/lib64/gcc/$TARGET/$GCC_VER/include" --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-checking --disable-werror --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-nls --disable-multilib --disable-libsanitizer --disable-libgomp --disable-libcilkrts --disable-libquadmath --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-bootstrap --with-system-zlib --with-pic --enable-poison-system-directories --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold
```

But somehow it seems that it is addind -fno-exceptions while building due to which when it goes ahead and tries to build libstdc++.so, the configure script fails saying

```
checking for exception model to use... configure: error: unable to detect exception model
```

I see that this is being printed while configuring gcc:

```
checking whether gcc supports -fno-exceptions... yes`
checking whether gcc supports -fno-rtti... yes
checking whether gcc supports -fasynchronous-unwind-tables... yes

g++ -c   -g -O2 -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc -I../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/build -I../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/../include  -I../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/../libcpp/include  \
-DBASEVER="\"5.4.0\"" -DDATESTAMP="\"\"" \
-DREVISION="\"\"" \
-DDEVPHASE="\"\"" -DPKGVERSION="\"(GCC) \"" \
-DBUGURL="\"<http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html>\"" -o build/version.o ../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/version.c
```

But I am not sure why -fno-exceptions is being taken when I did not specify this option

***UPDATE***

I tried to compile conftest.cpp

```
struct S { ~S(); };
void bar();
void foo()
{
  S s;
  bar();
}
```

using gcc5.4.0 and gcc4.9.2 that I had built
gcc4.9.2 one had these two elements which were missing in gcc5.4.0:

```
_Unwind_Resume
.cfi_personality
```

Comment: Does one of the flags you pass to `configure` cause the disabled exceptions?

Comment: I do not think so, since same flags had been used to build gcc-4.9.2 in the past.

Comment: As the requirement is to find the smallest complete example, I'd suggest you don't assume but find out instead!

Comment: Did you look in the corresponding config.log for details of how the exception model detection fails? Gcc may choose to use -fno-exceptions when compiling the compiler, but obviously not when compiling the standard library.

Comment: There was no extra message in config.log. All it printed was
`configure:15141: $? = 0
configure:15170: error: unable to detect exception model`
The configure script looks for one of these out of 4:
`_Unwind_SjLj_Resume
 _Unwind_SjLj_Register
 _Unwind_Resume
 __cxa_end_cleanup
`
in the .s generated but none was present

Answer (score 0):

Turns out **“--disable-bootstrap --with-system-zlib”** seemed to be disabling exceptions. Removed them and now conftest.cpp has _Unwind_Resume in the assembly generated using the new gcc. Thanks Ulrich Eckhardt.